# Having trouble understanding the use of certain symbol in code below

Tags: javascript

I saw this code:

```
secondHand.style.transform = rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg);
```

I am struggling with the symbol that is wrapped around the code `` `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)` ``. I have not seen a ` used in javascript code before. The key is known as the acute, back quote, grave, grave accent, left quote, open quote, or the push key.
Any explanations would be appreciated!

Comment: That construct is called a template literal. You can find out more about it [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: More specifically that's Template Literals doing variable interpolation. It's just like literal string concatenation but 10 times better. Literal string: `"rotate("+secondsDegrees+"deg)"` and Template Literal: `\`rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

``` `` ``` Those are called backticks, and they create a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for easier insertion of variable values into strings, in JavaScript.

Example:

```
const someName = 'Jack'

const someTemplateLiteral = `${someName} and Jill went up a hill`

console.log(someTemplateLiteral)
// logs:  'Jack and Jill went up a hill'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common string quote used in ES6 known as template literals.

Some commond examples:

```
`string text`

`string text line 1
 string text line 2`

`string text ${expression} string text`
```

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>   You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the
>   ES2015 specification.

Check here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you everyone, i really appreciate your help.